# I get an error when i use a variable value for the price in paypal sandbox telling me i require a non negative number

Tags: angular, typescript, paypal

I've tried to parse the return value to a number but it didn't help, the total works if i hard code the value to something like "1.50" but fails whenever i use the variable.

This is the function I use to add and return the final price

```js
getTotal() {
  let total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
    if (this.list[i].price) {
      total += this.list[i].price;
    }
  }
  return Number(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

This is the snippet where I set the price to send to paypal

```js
payment: (data, actions) => {
  return actions.payment.create({
    payment: {
      transactions: [{
        amount: {
          total: this.getTotal,
          currency: 'AUD'
        }
      }]
    }
  });
}
```

If I set `this.getTotal` to something like "1.50" I have no problem. But as it stands I get this error...

> "Currency amount must be non-negative number, may optionally contain
>   exactly 2 decimal places separated by '.'..."

Comment: I hope `this.list[i].price` is not treated as a string. just console log `total` before returning

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
return Number(total.toFixed(2))
```

Try:

```
return parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed your amount -> total accepts string as well.
So can u try this

```
   getTotal() {
      let total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
          if (this.list[i].price) {
              total += this.list[i].price;
          }
      }
      return total.toFixed(Math.max(2,2));
    }
```

As the error says it may optionally contain EXACTLY 2 decimal places.